# Python package import confusion

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

If I have a directory structure like:

```
.
└── pkg
    ├── A.py
    ├── B.py
    ├── C.py
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test
        └── script.py
```

Where `script.py` contains:

```
import pkg.B
import pkg.A

print pkg.A.test()
```

`A.py`:

```
import pkg.C

def test():
    return pkg.B.test()
```

`B.py`:

```
def test():
    return 'AAAA'
```

`C.py`:

```
def test3():
    return 'C.test3'
```

and `__init__.py` is empty.

if `A.py` imports `pkg.C`, then the code works. If I comment out that import, then it fails with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pkg/test/script.py", line 9, in <module>
    print pkg.A.test()
  File "/Users/X/Desktop/importtest/pkg/A.py", line 4, in test
    return pkg.B.test()
NameError: global name 'pkg' is not defined
```

changing `import pkg.C` to just `import pkg`, also works as long as `pkg.B` is imported in `script.py`.

If I comment out the import of `pkg.B` from `script.py`, then it doesn't make a difference if I `import pkg` or `import pkg.C` in `A.py`, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pkg/test/script.py", line 10, in <module>
    print pkg.A.test()
  File "/Users/X/Desktop/importtest/pkg/A.py", line 4, in test
    return pkg.B.test()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'B'
```

which is the behavior that I expect.

So the basic question is, why is `pkg.B.test()` accessible in `A.py` if `pkg.B` isn't imported there, if `pkg.B` is imported in `script.py` and `A.py` imports other sub-module?

I'm still a little unclear about the exact mechanism at work here is. An explanation or pointers to a good article describing the import logic would be most appreciated.

Comment: In Python 2.x you should always run code from the top-level directory, so `python pkg/test/script.py` and always use full imports `import pkg....` etc. This should solve any issues with imports. I don't fully understand it either.

Answer (score 2):

This question is a bit old, but I've stumbled upon it while having a similar issue. This is what I understand that's happening:

### Modules are imported once

The first thing we need to understand is that, [modules are loaded only once](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules)! This means that, if, for example, we have:

`X.py`:

```
import Z
import Y
blah blah
```

`Y.py`:

```
import Z
blah bloo
```

Running `X.py` will give us the following:

1. Module Z will be loaded in the first line.
2. Module Y will be run (as the consequence of `import Y`).
3. Although `import Z` is the first line in module `Y`, module `Z` is
   *not* loaded again.

**Note**: Anyway, whether a module is *loaded* or not, the *name* of the module is *imported* into the current namespace, making it accessible **but they are all referencing the same module object!!**.

### Importing sub modules

When importing a sub module, e.g., `pkg.A`, you are essentially loading the package `pkg` `__init__.py` module, and additionally, loading the A.py module. But also what you are doing is **adding the submodule as an attribute to the package's module**. I.e.:

```
>>> import pkg
>>> hasattr(pkg, 'A')
False
```

After restating the Python session:

```
>>> import pkg.A
>>> hasattr(pkg, 'A')
True
```

### Putting the pieces together

So, in `script.py` when `import pkg.B` is executed, the `pkg` module is loaded and the attribute `B` is added to its' module object. When `A.py` imports `pkg.C`, `pkg` is not loaded *because it was already loaded*, instead, the name `pkg` is imported into `A.py`'s namespace while *referencing the same module object* that was imported in `script.py`. Because the attribute `B` was added to that object (in `script.py`) `pkg.B.test` succeeds, even when it's executed in `A.py`.